# Subsetting Pandas Datetime Column (With Time Stamp) to Show Only Rows Before 3AM

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, subset

I have the following sample pandas data frame:

```
ID   Datetime_Col
1    2014-08-08 00:32:00
2    2016-01-25 23:25:00
3    2018-05-04 06:04:00
```

I want to subset it so that only rows with datetime before 3AM gets shown.

I originally tried extracting out the hour from datetime and creating a new column from that to later subset on .... but I think there's a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

New column is not necessary, filter by [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Datetime_Col'].dt.hour < 3]
print (df)
   ID        Datetime_Col
0   1 2014-08-08 00:32:00
```